# RecyclerView not updating items

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

MainFragment contains a RecyclerView of paths, when the user selects a path it navigates to CourseFragment which contains a RecyclerView of relevant courses. However, if the user goes back to choose a different path, the same course items are shown every time.

[image: Fragments and recyclerviews]

**Course Fragment**

```
class CourseFragment : Fragment(),
    CourseRecyclerAdapter.CourseItemListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: CourseViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Course Fragment onCreateView(): selectedItem = $globalSelectedPath")

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.courseRecyclerView)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host )
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.courseData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val adapter =
                CourseRecyclerAdapter(
                    requireContext(),
                    it,
                    this
                )
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        } )
        return view
    }
```

**CourseViewModel**

```
class CourseViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val courseDataRepository = CourseRepository(app)
    val courseData = courseDataRepository.courseData
    val selectedCourse = MutableLiveData<Course>()
}
```

**Course Repository**

```
class CourseRepository(val app: Application) {

    val courseData = MutableLiveData<List<Course>>()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            callWebService()
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun callWebService() {
        if (Utility.networkAvailable(app)) {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL).addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create()).build()
            val service = retrofit.create(CourseService::class.java)
            val serviceData = service.getCourseData(globalSelectedPath).body() ?: emptyList()
            courseData.postValue(serviceData)
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(app, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.noConnectivity), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

After logging it shows that CourseRepository is only called once, hence, the callWebService() is only triggered once, and new data is not retrieved.

```
2020-05-02 12:24:02.520 I/mylog: Course Fragment onCreateView(): selected path = MOB001
2020-05-02 12:24:02.529 I/mylog: Course Repository callWebService(): selected path = MOB001
-------------------------------
2020-05-02 12:24:35.009 I/mylog: Course Fragment onCreateView(): selected path = WEB999
```

To make sure i made an Okhttp interceptor log of the callWebService() which confirmed that data was only fetched once:

```
    12:24:02.551 D/OkHttp: --> GET https://.../mobile/feed/course_data.php?pathName=MOB001
    12:24:02.551 D/OkHttp: --> END GET
    12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://.../mobile/feed/course_data.php?pathName=MOB001 (455ms)
    12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: date: Sat, 02 May 2020 09:24:03 GMT
    12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: server: Apache
    12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: x-powered-by: PHP/5.6.40
    12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: vary: Accept-Encoding
    12:24:03.007 D/OkHttp: content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    12:24:03.009 D/OkHttp: [{"courseName":"Android App Development Essentials","instructor":"John Lennon","courseDescription":"Description ...","courseImage":"android_development_essentials.jpg","instructorImage":"john.jpg"}]
    12:24:03.009 D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (206-byte body)
```

Comment: I think your `Course fragment ` not created view every time or another chance is that your `ViewModel's` data still present sot it showing previous data. How you open your course fragment from course selection?

Comment: I supose that if the user select a path in the MainFragment and the CourseFragment should shows the result, how the service knows which is the path? I don´t see the path in the callWebService, only build the retrofit instance with the WEB_SERVICE_URL but the any path, so how the services knows which is the selected course?

Comment: @Manuel Mato, I am currently using a project level variable (globalSelectedVaible) in a seperate file to store the path, and it is initialized in the first fragment in function onPathItemClick()

Comment: val serviceData = service.getCourseData(globalSelectedPath).body() ?: emptyList()

Comment: Navigation component can prevent the fragment recreation, so check if the MainFragment recreates the view because if the view is not recreated, then is not possible to fetch more data with the current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the following line:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)
```

I had used `requireActivity()` which will scope my fragment's viewmodel to the activity lifecycle, so the RecyclerView will update correctly when the app (and therefore activity) first starts but does not update again when navigating forth and back between fragments.

So to solve this issue i replaced `requireActivity()` with `this` which means the viewmodel is scoped to the fragment it is in only and therefore the RecyclerView will update whenever the user enters and re-enters the fragment

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that is issue is cause because the observer is not getting updated. You could use Fragment's view lifecycle through getViewLifeCycleOwner() or getViewLifeCycleLiveData() so that LiveData will remove observers every single time the fragment is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()) cause the retrieve the previous view model because the view model store keeps reference to previously created view model then serve it if you want again. You should give the fragment as a view model store owner rather than activity. Additionally I think your repository design is not correct if you don't need same course list in another place, you should call the method with corresponding argument whenever the course list fragment is created so you retrieve the appropriate data from server.

Comment: i got your point and you could be correct, however, i passed in requireParentFragment() instead of requireActivity(), but still same issue.

Comment: Regarding the Repository Design, i agree that i should pass the path argument to the repository but i need to make a factory class, which was my intention after solving this problem.

Comment: You can try this rather than require parent fragment because in your case it is probably null or point to same problem. Also I wonder where do you call callWebService() method?

Comment: callWebService() is called within CourseRespository inside the coroutines block.